# How to Show Accurate Category Post Count?

Tags: php, wordpress, categories

I've got some code in my blog sidebar that is designed to show the number of posts in a particular category.  It works, kind of.  It will only show up to the number 5 and then it stops updating the post count.  Any ideas on how to fix?

Here's the code for one of the categories:

```
<?php 
   $count_posts = get_posts('post_type=post&category_name=Software') 
?>
   <li id="nav1">
   <a class="<?php if ($current_cat == get_cat_ID('Software')) echo "software-active active"; ?>" href="<?php echo get_category_link(get_cat_ID('Software')) ?>" title="Software">Software (<?php echo count($count_posts) ?>)</a>
```

Here's a [link to the blog](http://iqnavigator.com/blog/).  thanks for your help!

Comment: I'd really recommend writing your code so it's easily human readable. Especially if you're going to ask for help on SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change:

```
get_posts('post_type=post&category_name=Software')
```

To:

```
get_posts('post_type=post&category_name=Software&numberposts=-1');
```

Comment: Thanks, that totally fixed it.